# Regex to split the string into identical blocks

Tags: python, regex

I wanted to fetch the data an put it in the list from the below XML using regex in python as below

`[['ip-address','1.1.1.1/16','protocol','ospf','ll',4],['ip-address','3.3.3.3/32','ip-addr','2.2.2.2','ip-addr','8.8.8.8','type',route]]`

```
a=''' <att>
       <rt>
        <rts>
         <ip-address>1.1.1.1/16</ip-address>
         <bb>
          <cc>
           <protocol>ospf</protocol>
          </cc>
         </bb>
         <ee>
          <ff>
           <ll>4</ll>
          </ff>
         </ee>
        </rts>
        <rts>
         <ip-address>3.3.3.3/32</ip-address>
         <bb>
          <cc>
           <ip-addr>2.2.2.2</ip-addr>
           <ip-addr>8.8.8.8</ip-addr>
          </cc>
         </bb>
         <ee>
          <ff>
           <type>route</type>
          </ff>
         </ee>
        </rts>
       <rt>
      </att>'''
```

My approach was to divide the above single string into multiple string and then search, example

```
  b=  '''<rts>
         <ip-address>1.1.1.1/16</ip-address>
         <bb>
          <cc>
           <protocol>ospf</protocol>
          </cc>
         </bb>
         <ee>
          <ff>
           <ll>4</ll>
          </ff>
         </ee>
        </rts>'''

 c= '''<rts>
         <ip-address>3.3.3.3/32</ip-address>
         <bb>
          <cc>
           <ip-addr>2.2.2.2</ip-addr>
           <ip-addr>8.8.8.8</ip-addr>
          </cc>
         </bb>
         <ee>
          <ff>
           <type>route</type>
          </ff>
         </ee>
        </rts>'''
```

I used the following regex to create multiple string

```
regex = re.findall(r"<(rts)>.*<\ /rts)", a, re.S)
```

But it fetches all untill the end of string as below,

```
        <rts>
     <ip-address>1.1.1.1/16</ip-address>
     <bb>
      <cc>
       <protocol>ospf</protocol>
      </cc>
     </bb>
     <ee>
      <ff>
       <ll>4</ll>
      </ff>
     </ee>
    </rts>
    <rts>
     <ip-address>3.3.3.3/32</ip-address>
     <bb>
      <cc>
       <ip-addr>2.2.2.2</ip-addr>
       <ip-addr>8.8.8.8</ip-addr>
      </cc>
     </bb>
     <ee>
      <ff>
       <type>route</type>
      </ff>
     </ee>
    </rts>
```

Is there a way I could be able to divide the string as "b" and "c" shown above?

Comment: parsing XML with regular expressions is generally bad idea. Consider using appropriate special libraries

Comment: As for your regex, you should adjust it to non-greedy match `.*?`

Comment: Python has a built-in library for parsing XML, [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

Comment: I think you just need some lxml xpath queries and you get this much more easily than with regex.

Answer (score 1):

With lxml and xpath you can parse xml much more easily than by rolling your own regex parser.

Here's an example:

```
import lxml
import StringIO

a =''' <att>
       <rt>
        <rts>
         <ip-address>1.1.1.1/16</ip-address>
         <bb>
          <cc>
           <protocol>ospf</protocol>
          </cc>
         </bb>
         <ee>
          <ff>
           <ll>4</ll>
          </ff>
         </ee>
        </rts>
        <rts>
         <ip-address>3.3.3.3/32</ip-address>
         <bb>
          <cc>
           <ip-addr>2.2.2.2</ip-addr>
           <ip-addr>8.8.8.8</ip-addr>
          </cc>
         </bb>
         <ee>
          <ff>
           <type>route</type>
          </ff>
         </ee>
        </rts>
       </rt>
      </att>'''   

f = StringIO.StringIO(a)
tree = lxml.etree.parse(f)

rts = tree.xpath('//rts')

ipa = rts[0].xpath(".//ip-address")[0]

print ipa.text
```

This prints the first ip-address of the first rts tag, i.e. 1.1.1.1/16.

Note:
I needed to fix your xml, there was a / missing on the last rt tag.